# NVT I2C bus capacitance

Tags: i2c, nxp

I would like to use [NXP NVT20XX](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NVT2003_04_06.pdf) as bidirectional voltage-level translator in my system (I2C at 100kHz, 6 slaves) and I only don't understand one thing. I am little bit confused.
In the datasheet they said:

> Bit widths ranging from 1-bit or 2-bit are offered for level translation application with transmission speeds < 33 MHz for an open-drain system with a 50 pF capacitance and a pull-up of 197 Ω

And my question is what does it mean this 50pF? Does it say that I can use ony 1 slave (SCL, SDA Input Capacitance (CBIN) = 60oF)?

Answer (score 1):

50 pF is load capacitance in this case.  It's the bus capacitance downstream of the level shifter.  Further in the datasheet you see C<sub>L(tot)</sub>= 50 pF in a few places.

197 Ω is a very small pull-up resistor.  Typical I2C slave device can't pull against such a stiff pull-up.  I suspect you would need a weaker pull-up.

50 pF is a fairly small value for I<sup>2</sup>C bus capacitance.  If you have a larger bus capacitance and weaker pull-up, you should still be able to use this level shifter at a slower bus speed (the usual 100kHz or 400kHz).